# Export div to pdf in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, jspdf

I have two divs with ids: `element1` and `element2`

In between these divs, there is a button. After these divs, there is one more button with id: `pdf`.

In the divs there is a table and input box.

```html
    <div id="element1">
      Enter your name: <input><br>
      Enter your class: <input>
    </div>

    <button>Click on the button</button>

    <div id="element2">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Class</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input></td>
          <td><input></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <button id="pdf">Create pdf</button>
```

I am a beginner at JS. Now, I want to create a pdf file including the contents of both the divs excluding both the buttons. Also, the pdf file must contain the values entered in input box. The pdf can contain the contents of div in any format like text or jpg.

Please help me as I am a beginner. I have tried much with jspdf but it is not giving me the output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

jspdf is the right library to begin with. What you can do is to manipulate your data before you put it inside the pdf. I think your best choose is to replace the inputs with  or  or what ever element you want. Then you can build your pdf. My choose is to put it inside wrapper

```js
$('#pdf').click(function () {
    $('#PDFWrapper').find('input').each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).after('<span>' + $(this).val() + '</span>');
    });
    $('#PDFWrapper').find('button').hide();
        
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.fromHTML($('#PDFWrapper').html(), 10, 10, {
        'elementHandlers': {}
    });
    doc.save('download.pdf');
        
    $('#PDFWrapper').find('input').each(function(){
        $(this).show();
        $(this).next().remove();
    });
    $('#PDFWrapper').find('button').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<div id="PDFWrapper">
  <div id="element1">
    Enter your name: <input><br>
    Enter your class: <input>
  </div>

  <button>Click on the button</button>

  <div id="element2">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Class</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input></td>
        <td><input></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="pdf">Create pdf</button>
```

Comment: It's working in jsfiddle, but when I paste it in notepad, its not working. Please give me the list of plugins used in this.

Comment: 1. Check if you putted your references inside <head> tag    
2. Check if you putted java script code inside <script> tag     
3. if you put your java script code inside head you must wrap it with `$(document).ready(function(){ CODE GOES HERE });`